# How to access values in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the values stored in a list in my react component. When looped through, all data can be accessed but cannot be accessed by the syntax { variable.data_key }

code: https://pastebin.com/wS5SL22n

line 9: I initialized a list of data
line 36: I started looping through the list of data.
line 38: I created a table and tried to access items from the data list.
line 55: take the table as state
line 79: displaying the contents

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /* DATABASE */
    const movies = [
      {
        id: 0,
        src:
          "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/7WsyChQLEftFiDOVTGkv3hFpyyt.jpg",
        title: "movie one",
        overview: "overview one"
      }
    ];

    let movieRows = [];

    /* LOOPING THROUGH DATABASE */
    movies.forEach(item => {
      /* MAKING AN ELEMENT */
      const moveDataTable = (
        <table key={movies.id}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img alt="poster" width="80" src={movies.src} />
              </td>
              <td>{movies.title}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
      /* PUSING DATA TO THE LIST */
      movieRows.push(moveDataTable);
      console.log(movieRows);
    });

    this.state = { rows: movieRows };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p> {this.state.rows} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: all data can be accessed means,
when I loop through an array I can iterate through all elements
but I cannot access id, title etc values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accepted an answer but still, I want to provide a different logic.

The main problem here you are trying to reach the wrong item. You are trying with `movies` but in your `forEach` loop it is `item`. Though, I don't recommend using `forEach` like that then set the state. At some point, there might be some glitches. Use `map` for such situations. Also, do not use your constructor like defining your functions.

```js
const movies = [
  {
    id: 0,
    src:
      "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/7WsyChQLEftFiDOVTGkv3hFpyyt.jpg",
    title: "movie one",
    overview: "overview one"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "moview two",
    overview: "something"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
    state = { movies: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState( {movies} );
  }

  createTable = () => (
    <table key={movies.id}>
      <tbody>
      { 
        movies.map( movie =>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img alt="poster" width="80" src={movie.src} />
              </td>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.overview}</td>
            </tr>
        )
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.createTable()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started react today and I am following a  tutorial. Can you please suggest me an in-depth tutorial that is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: You are welcome. Official documentation is a good one to start with. Personally, I can suggest Andrew Mead's and Stephen Grider's courses on Udemy if you afford to pay a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

`movies` is an array, not an object.

`movies.forEach(item => ...)` means for each `item` in the `movies` array. The individual item in the array is `item`, not `movies`. You are trying to display `movies.src` and `movies.title`. There is no `src` or `title` property on the `movies` *array*. These properties are on the `item` in the array. You should be using `item.src` and `item.title`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing movie.id i needed to access item.id as i named the variable as item in the `foreach loop`.